# Run script on closing web page

Tags: javascript

I have java script code I wanted to work on closing the page only.
Its working fine on closing the page but also working on page change, when I change the page the url getting execute in ajax. Which I don’t want.
Can someone sees my code and adjusted to work on page close only not changing the page.

Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(window).unload(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url:"clean.php",
    type:"POST",
    async:false, // so browser waits till xhr completed
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: As far as browsers are concerned, closing a page (tab) and navigating to a new page are essentially the same thing.'

Comment: If you leave the current page you are on for any reason including a refresh. It is considered closing a web page.

Comment: there's any way of just closing the page only. not changing it, the script should work on closing page only?

Comment: The only event you've got is the "unload" event, and the browser fires it for both situations.

Comment: you can have your clean.php script wait 5 seconds for a confirmation from a new page, which informs the clean.php to stop. if nobody tells it to stop, the tab was closed or left to a new site instead of re-navigating your site.